# Dead man switch that would resist a nation-backed offensive

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, politics, security, protection

JE is a famous man that has an extensive amount of information incriminating the powerful of this world.

He would like to ensure that an "unfortunate accident" does not happen to him by clever use of this compromising information. He is therefore looking for a solid dead man switch that would have at least have the following characteristics:

- release of the documents (can be digitalized) when not acknowledged for some time, or when the acknowledgement is not correct
- inability to modify the documents once they are in the vault
- resistance to electronic warfare (decryption)

These requirements are simple to satisfy technologically;

- resistance to torture: JE could be tortured

  - to reveal the people who hold the information, so there must not be reliance on the typical "*Marc: if I do not talk to you once every 3 days, send these papers to the press and the justice*"
  - to disable the dead man switch
- resistance to a nation-backed effort to block the documents. This would be a secret operation (say, the President would like to quietly use some of the country shady forces to do [something] - but not a nuclear strike), so the protection must stay in the realms of realism

These requirements are the ones I do not exactly know how to satisfy.

Other reasonable requirements are welcome. Everything happens contemporary, in our world with our technology and political context

Comment: I find it inappropriate how a hypothetical question (and anything else would be off-topic here) is mixed with thinly disguised real names. I suggest you edit this.

Comment: @o.m. I did that on purpose. Not really because I have a stake in the game (I am French and not that interested in US affairs), but because this will provide a clear context people can relate to. The "victim" having money and power, against strong unofficial-but-very-real ones. I am honestly surprised that he did not prepare such a protective system (and this was the reason for my question, after having been reminded of this affair on the radio). Also - how is this off-topic? (I am honestly  curious and since you have high rep you will know)

Comment: @WoJ I believe they were referring to this site being for the purposes of hypothetical questions only, and stating any question that isn't purely hypothetical in nature is off-topic. It wasn't (as I understand it) a statement that your question is off-topic, just clarifying why you should make it more clearly hypothetical

Comment: If blackmailing the wrong person, this kind of setup seems to *invite* an attack. Perhaps some Great Leader is less worried about his assorted peccadilloes becoming public than about, say, appearing weak in the eyes of various rivals for power. Perhaps people will act in a way that seems reasonable *to you*, but perhaps they have other motivations and they will act in ways that surprise you. Oh, and drugging seems a more effective way to retrieve the passphrase than torture. The torture is just for the Great Leader's enjoyment.

Comment: @BenjaminHollon: yes, it is completely hypothetical. The allusion to a well-known figure is to put a clear context on the kind of forces at stake.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to remove the thinly veiled reference to Epstein - it detracts from the actual question, and can be reworded with no detriment

Answer (score 7):

There are a few pretty good hardware suggestions already posted to trigger a switch, I would like to expand on how you can make this message incredibly tough to scrub from the internet for the torturers of your protagonist.

The following only really works assuming that the internet is running as it does now with decentralized networks readily accessible and maintained.

Real projects exploring the idea are: https://killcord.io/ and https://sarcophagus.io/ - they work on the similar principles - 10,000s of copies of the encrypted message are owned by nodes either on the Ethereum network or IPFS network which are maintained regardless of their content.

Upon "death", that is, failure to enter in a liveness password to a smart contract usually on Ethereum after some fixed time period, a key is released to the blockchain that allows anyone to decrypt the encrypted message alongside emails to any relevant parties to look at the entries - the dead man's switch can be disabled or triggered directly using appropriate commands to this smart contract.

I would also expand a little on how to handle the "under duress" scenario for your crypto-savvy protagonist, it's possible to modify the above ideas to use either:

1. Deniable Encryption: which is a method to provide keys which decode the encrypted message to something related but not exactly the original information your character is attempting to smuggle.
2. Steganography: decrypting your data to files which appear compromising but actually contain the truly compromising information within them as carefully chosen flipped bits.

Both of these could fool a would-be torturer into thinking they got the information but actually end up disseminating them to the public in a slightly more hidden fashion.

Comment: Good idea, but ... Nation A says "hey, these crypto-currency thingies fund cybercrime and terror. Let's ban them. Are you with us or against us?" Nation N says "hey, do you realize how much energy they burn? Let them pay carbon certificates out of their nose. Are you with us or are you against us?" These infrastructures are pretty insane if you look at them clearly.

Comment: @o.m. I guess as a defense I'd say the following: so long as global ban doesn't take place, the ledger will still exist, if a nation chooses to censor a crypto token the ledger will still probably be accessible unless all mirrors and communication to owners of mirrors are banned. If somehow, all cryptos were destroyed globally, then distributed ledger technology would probably still exist and it would be possible to perform a similar trick (like in IPFS mentioned above).

Comment: it's hard to oppose nation-backed efforts, especially if they can keep torturing the protagonist to buy them more time. Nations can infiltrate and eventually compromise even large blockchains, forcing hard forks.

Comment: @Alexander This is true, assuming that things stay as they are, the protagonist must find a way to circumvent the nation forcing a hard fork. However, if we're a little more creative we can make the dead man's switch commit a new encrypted message every N blocks - making this very hard to censor unless the nation removes the ability to store long strings entirely.

Answer (score 6):

#### Get a postal / hotel / etc worker to inadvertently send the documents to the media for you.

I don't know about the rest of the world, but in Australia you can address mail to "C/O <a specific post office>", they will hold it for you and you can go and collect it with ID. If you don't collect it within 6 weeks, they return it to sender.

Many hotels will also hold mail for a limited period for guests who haven't arrived yet.

Who hold what for how long is probably best determined by experimentation in advance, (just send some test letters and see what happens to them).

1. Put your incriminating evidence on a microSD or some other small, dense media.
2. Put the microSD card in an envelope packed with some blank A4 pages.
3. Address it to either an alias that you have a fake ID for, or a slight misspelling of your name, care of a post office or hotel. "Jefary Eipstiin, C/O Gold Coast Resort Post Office, QLD, Australia."
4. Write the return address as your chosen reporter. "Sender: Bob Woodward. 1 watergate road."
5. If all goes well. Rock up at the post office and ask for any mail for you. Collect it, put it in a new envelope addressed to another post office with a new stamp, and mail it immediately.
6. If the government attacks you, arrests you, or you die, ~6 weeks later the post office will return the mail to "sender", delivering them to the reporter for you.
7. If there is mass surveillance, by having the mail in an alias or mispelling of your name, its unlikely to be found by an investigation doing a massive government database search, at least not before the 6 weeks timer runs out.

Also worth keeping another copy in a safe place - safe deposit box in a bank kinda thing - if you're captured and tortured it'd be handy to give your torturers something so they stop torturing you.

Comment: This is assuming he can hold out on torture for ~6 weeks (depending on if they capture him soon after renewing the hold). They can just torture him and ask "Where is/who has the data store?" and he could tell them at the post office on hold. I would assume that shady government forces could then get it, by illegal means if necessary.

Comment: @TheLittlePeace Just keep another copy of it in a safe deposit box in your name to give up in torture. You don't really want to cancel the media drop, you just want the torture to stop.

Comment: I wanted to argue that this doesn't make it immune to torture, but then I realized the OP only asked for torture *resistance*, so that still works. Maybe have multiple safe deposits though, since the torture will almost certainly continue. After all, why would someone have a single copy of such critically important information? He must be hiding something.

Comment: A "nation backed offensive" likely has nations wide surveillance. It seems trivial to check if this person is mailing stuff and intercept the package. Even just shadowing the guy for a few weeks/months and you'll see a pattern emerging. After that you can track his mail, check each mail on his writing, way of spelling and aliases, or the journalists trusted to spread the information. It seems too many points of failure after just a few stake-outs or video surveillance.

Comment: @Ash Any organization willing to use such methods won't stop.  (Why would they?  They know about such subterfuges as well.)  The will follow up on disclosures but also will continue to apply duress until it is overwhelmingly clear that the subject's will has been irrecoverably broken.

Answer (score 6):

Custom electronic devices, at least a dozen of them. They use pre-paid SIMs, are plugged into the grid somewhere. At least a dozen of them, scattered across the country (or several countries). These devices are programmed to contact each other periodically, which is at least every 3 minutes.

Each device contains a copy of the documents, and if it sees any other device drop out, it emails the documents to major news outlets, tweets them, everything.

Thus, to disable these, one would have to find all of them and disable them simultaneously. If you got 11 of the 12, the 12th just finishes the job. You thought there were 12? Oops, actually 13.

And he checks in by hitting some Onion (Tor) url. If he misses a checkin, they send the documents. He could even have a second address, which if that one is pinged the documents release immediately along with a "I'm being tortured" note.

This doesn't rely on other people (except to design/test the devices initially). He can be under surveillance before arrest/detainment/abduction. There's no secret information he has which can be cheated out of him or guessed... he may set it up so that he doesn't even know the location of the devices, the number, or any of the technical details. It may be designed so it can never be disarmed (just that new documents can be added to it). And of course, the devices can scan headlines looking for "Joffrey Epplestchien dead" keywords and trigger on that as well.

Of course, likely needs to hire a hitman to deal with the people who implement the system. Just like the guy who designs the castle secret passageways, those people aren't going to come to a good end.

Comment: "That eipstien guy we just arrested. I ran his finances and noticed he's paying like 13 mobile phone plans on devices all over the country. Either he's got a tonne of mistresses, or something freaky is going on. They don't move, so they're not people. Maybe they're his backup servers."

Comment: @Ash You missed this part *"They use pre-paid SIMs"*.

Comment: Maybe it's different in different countries, but prepaid sims need in Australia need a tonne of ID to get and that's all associated with you. Last one I got needed more paperwork than my mortgage.

Comment: This. That a good one. No need for hitman - strenth of the systemnot in not knowing about it, it does not matter if knowledge is available. Needs just setup it properly.

Comment: The first power failure, electronic component failure on one of the devices (which does happen), or cellular network outage will trigger a premature release of the data.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan All doomsday devices threaten to go off prematurely. That's why they're scary as fuck. That's why you don't mess with the people who can make them. Instead of waterboarding such a person, you give them a helicopter and a satchelful of charged batteries (so to speak). And considering how one-sided the doomsday I describe might be, that only makes it more true not less.

Comment: Fake ID, bank checking account and debit card, cheap virtual hosting service -> free running server for years.

Comment: As a computer engineer with some background on fail-safe systems and network communications, this is guaranteed to go off in less than a year. One day a server will hang or blow up, the communication will fail for some minutes or hours and the other devices will interpret this technical problem as an attack on JE's network and send the information to the press. One problem with doomsday devices is that you only want them to provoke doom on the required day. This is guaranteed not to wait for your instructions.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Ups, I hadn't read your comment. Yes, pretty much that.

Comment: @JohnO No, that's the reason nobody makes them. A doomsday device that not just threatens, but it is certain that it will go off prematurely is just a sofisticated suicide machine.

Comment: @Rekesoft Tell that to the Soviet Union.

Comment: @JohnO I would, but 1) the Soviet Union no longer exists, and 2) they didn't have a doomsday device to start with. The so-called "Dead hand" system was a multi-layered failsafe protocol that 1) Once activated by the high-command in prevision of a nuclear attack, 2) after checking by numerous and independent checking systems that a nuclear strike had been made on the Soviet Union, 3) if no connection could be made with the high-command after a reasonable amount of time 4) transferred authority of the launching codes to the crew of the bunker. So, hardly the same case.

Comment: @Rekesoft You got me. The Soviets were definitely known with being careful about such things, and since there's no way you'd read the most generous interpretation of Dead Hand so as to win an internet argument, it can only be that I'm wrong and that you weren't wallowing in old pro-Soviet propaganda. It's not as if the arming codes for nukes were once "00000000" because it was the easiest number to dial into the device or anything.

Comment: @JohnO I'm not going to enter in a contest of who has swallowed more propaganda. Your system is guaranteed to send all the sensible information in less than a year, leaving a lot of very powerful people very angry with JE, and nothing to lose anymore. The soviet "dead-hand", which maybe even doesn't exist and it's only western scare propaganda, has not yet started Armaggedon. So either they didn't make this kind of trigger-happy designs at all, or they aren't that trigger-happy after all.

Comment: @Rekesoft My system guarantees no such thing, except for ultra-hyperbolic definitions of "guarantee" that brainwashed propaganda-sucking imbeciles use. While it isn't robust and does risk such, it doesn't invalidate the premise. The risk of such a crazy scheme that can't be called back in class Failsafe-fashion is a feature, not a bug. This is a "nuke" that only hurts the enemy, after all, JE won't die from radiation poisoning. Also, nice downvote, I definitely deserve that for an answer given in good faith.

Comment: @JohnO Weeeee, calm down, cowboy! If a downvote hurts so much, don't make me call the moderators for calling me imbecile. They might even told your mummy so she can scold you properly. Nobody is giving you millions of dollars if your answer gets chosen, so you may moderate your level of aggresivity at criticisms. I've downvoted your question because I don't think it answers the question, and I've left a comment explaining why. The only thing you had to do is editing your answer adding some sort of mechanism to prevent unwanted activations and I'd had upvoted  your answer, you retarded tween.

Comment: @Rekesoft I'm perfectly calm. Your comments add nothing. I did not call you any names, it's merely a coincidence that you use words poorly in the same way that imbeciles do so. I personally blame the public school system. As for the downvote, I know for a fact that you carefully evaluated all the other answers here for their technical merit, and that you've downvoted all the rest just like mine. Right? As for your explanation, it seems that your occupational frustration is more deserving than my effort-ful, honest, and good answer is.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a digital archive (e.g. a zip file) with the documents. Create a private/public key pair, sign the file, destroy the private key and publish the public key.
   Now anyone can validate the integrity of the archive and nobody, not even you, can make a new version. (This step has a slight weakness regarding the nation-state criterion. A breakthrough in quantum computing or a giant server farm could make additional, altered versions of the archive to muddle the waters.)
2. Describe an encryption scheme which relies on several one-time-keys. That can be as simple as a bitwise addition. Create more keys than you need. Encrypt the original with different variations of keys, creating multiple ciphertexts.
   Now anyone with one ciphertext and the right keys for that text can decrypt your archive. If the result is a signed zip, obviously the elements matched. If not, try again with another combo.
3. Spread the ciphertexts and keys to lawyers in different countries who are paid to release them if certain conditions are fulfilled.
   You are betting that enough ciphertexts and keys will be released so that a matching set is among them. How many you need depends on your need for certainty. (This can be made weak, with risk of non-release, or strong, with risk of premature release. Remember that anything you know is presumed to be spilled, so it cannot simply be "I posted a selfie on Facebook." Make it a condition that shows freedom of action: "I visited my villas in 5 out of 10 locations last year and got pictured by paparazzi." The character might know that he has to arrange being photographed, but if he can travel that wide he is free.)
4. Pay several terminally ill lawyers or bankers to arrange the data-holders from step 3 for you. People whose medical prognosis looks bad. Make sure that none of them has a *complete* set of ciphertext-and-keys, to limit the damage if they have a recovery and then get pressured.
   Once the expected happens (no need for foul play if enough ill intermediaries were involved) you cannot recall the messages.

Bonus feature: powerful people will know what happens when you are sued and have to sell your villas abroad, or if you even have to turn your passport in.

Comment: Re: "lawyers in different countries who are paid to release", a state actor will be able to follow the money trail to neutralize all the individuals involved.   Re: "if he can travel that wide he is free" or a skilled actor is portraying him with the cooperation of authorities to reinforce the illusion.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan, hence the cut-outs with terminally ill intermediaries. Sufficiently good actors are indeed a problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Ignorance Is Bliss:

This kind of deadman news release can have two functions, and the answer will be slightly different if it's only about releasing the data. So I'll assume the primary motivation is to make JE immune to attacks or imprisonment by the threatened governments and/or organizations. To make this work, you must set up conditions such that no matter what the governments do, they always believe the information will be released if JE dies under any circumstances OR is imprisoned any more than momentarily.

The best way to guarantee you can't influence or control the release of the data is to no longer control its release yourself. You need some shadowy figures involved that JE is not directly aware of. Then these people are in charge of monitoring JE and assuring that the predetermined set of conditions are met. If JE is a public figure, he must agree to a set of conditions:

- **Let your enemies know about your plans**: Obvious, but everyone who is being blackmailed must know. If, however, you let enemies of the government know, you're painting a bullseye on your back for anyone who WANTS the release of the info.
- **Be sure the information being released isn't known to your agents, and can't be understood until it is released**: This could probably be achieved with some kind of coding or blind information-mating. If your agents (who, after all, you DON'T know) are able to view the information, they may use it themselves to blackmail the government, making it's use to JE greatly diminished.
- **Remain a public figure**: If JE is free, then the shadow agents don't release the data. This could mean JE must show up at a certain public place on a regular basis, tying him to a place. Or, imagining JE to be so high profile that they make the news, the data is released if JE disappears for a predetermined amount of time or dies.
- **JE agrees to the release of protected health information to an undisclosed place**: If JE gets sick, he must go through a certain health network. His doctors agree to release a copy of his health records to an anonymous file destination (form TBD) so if he has a short-term health emergency, the data isn't released.
- **Entrust the arrangements to a terminally ill employee**: You need someone who is totally loyal to JE, but is dying. They take the money to pay the shadow agents, find them, set up the preconditions, and then die. The secret of who has the files is gone.

Even if the terminally ill employee lied and didn't set up anything, JE will firmly believe the loyal employee did. Under torture or drugs, it will be determined that keeping JE prisoner or killing him is counterproductive. In fact, it might even be MORE effective if the dead employee never set up shadow agents - after all, you can never disprove a conspiracy that you believe to be true, but isn't. There would always be the doubt that they were out there waiting to release the data.

I would couple this with a more conventional deadman-release method just in case there was a failure in the process, or the  shadow agents fail to perform. But JE's enemies couldn't do anything to JE to get the info, since  JE doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

**sensors coupled with low frequency emitters inside the body**

**Signals**

First off, you need to determine if the person is still alive. Easiest to do this is by having a sensor that measures heart rate. No pulse and the information is sent. Embed the sensors in the body, possibly multiple, to make them hard to reach.

Second, you need to be able to send a signal to your vault when the person is diseased. Low frequency signals are difficult to block. They are sometimes referred to as 'slow', but in truth it's the information density that is at stake. You simply cannot cram a lot of information over time. This isn't a problem, as your message can be short. Just an 'ok' or a 'release' message, however coded, is enough. Release always has priority. If multiple signals are detected it'll release (expect only one!) And if it's garbled it will release after a time if it doesn't get the ok signal in time. It is important to get a different signal within a longer period of time, like a physical button or via protected internet or something, to make sure the signal hasn't been replaced.

That thus means one standard method, with some factor authentication if required.

Sensors can also find increased stress levels from injury or threats. If this is prolonged, like in a torture situation, the signal is sent. Same for not expected anesthetics and the like. This to prevent them accessing the sensors in the body without stress response. If sensors are disconnected, they should also give off the signal.

Finally the switch can be triggered by the person himself in multiple ways. Like saying some words or the like. That way, even if the person isn't in direct danger but held captive, he can still trigger his weapon.

The sensors and the like should use as little magnetic materials as possible to prevent EMP attacks.

**Documents**

To secure the documents you can use signing. If you've ever encrypted documents with, for example, PGP, you know that tampering becomes quite difficult. Not just because you can encrypt them, but sign them. The document itself is used for this, so if the document is changed, the signature will show this discrepancy.

With a ton of huge servers around the world, the documents can be encrypted at multiple owned locations as well as hidden on existing servers. Include some air gapped systems that dump everything on the internet or other media that is available and can update only periodically (or not at all. You have enough dirt already!), you can protect yourself from nearly any full scale attack.

**Additional methods**

The use of this deadman switch is multifold. Regardless who attacks this person, everyone is at stake. That means many people and/or nations will actually facilitate many things to prevent the death, torture or other release scenario's. That also means many state defences can assist the person in protecting him and the data. That way the person can even have the encrypted documents at a nuclear silo facility or the like, or even request his own secret sattelites to receive the signal and release documents when needed. Make him comfortable and safe.

Comment: Low frequency emitter = physically long antenna.  This creates 2 problems:  1) long antennas are much more easily affected by EMP; 2) long antennas are much harder to hide in the body.  Also, even low frequency signals will be impeded in many locations and blocked completely in a Faraday cage.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 True. I made the mistake of thinking of low magnetic waves to thwart the Faraday cage. Any suggestions on the signalling?

Comment: Part 1.  It's tricky - there's no such thing as perfect security, especially when opposed by a nation state.  I'd keep the transmitter as a worn external device that must send a (multiply rerouted) mobile network / satellite signal to the data vault at least every x hours and routinely every x/4 hours.  X needs to be long enough to allow for legitimate out-of-comms-range activities and situations but short enough that activation key can't be tortured out within that period.

Comment: Part 2.  Signal that is transmitted includes constant biometrics log and proximity to embedded smart chip/s (probably in the forearm).  If biometrics log + chip proximity indicates that device has been removed or that torture has occurred or signal is simply not received for >x hours then information release time.  Not perfect - info release could happen accidentally if the device went flat, or JE is in sustained pain from a car crash / kinky sex or the device is simply damaged.  Also possible that a nation state could transfer the device and chip to another person if trigger specs known.

Comment: Part 3.  Intentionally defeating the protocol would be much, much harder if a code that could not be predicted needed to be entered each time a signal was due to be sent.  However, not possible for a person to memorise what is basically a one time pad with thousands of entries for each year, and anything short of a one time pad could be broken by a motivated nation state easily by observation through surveillance.

Answer (score 2):

**To resist torture**

1. The deadman switch is an opt-out mechanism with a short recycle timer. Torture takes *time*. Torture becomes more endurable if the amount of it you have to withstand is a known value. If the victim is being tortured, and knows there's only a few hours left on the deadman, he is very likely to be able to do some combination of stalling/enduring to reach a point of no return at which point he is free to fully co-operate with his captors.  Depending on the state of due process in the likely scenarios, anything from 24 hours to two weeks is a reasonable recycle rate.
2. Have a panic button. Some way to give a false instruction, or a seemingly analogous process that, instead of resetting the switch, triggers the deadman action. In the event he is even *threatened* with torture or death unless he complies, he can announce that he has a deadman switch, even describe it's nature.  Now his captors have to make a choice: believe him, and convince him to disarm it (at which point he can hit the panic button instead), or disbelieve him and the torture is now irrelevant to the deadman, because they're not after information about the deadman.

**Resistance to gov't interference with mechanism**

1. Self-publish. Generally speaking the only way a gov't can control a release of information is through censorship. Once data is outside their control, it's too damned late.  Shotgunning the information to as broad a mailing list as possible is sufficient - by the time the gov't sends an instruction to whatever systems to stop the flow of information it's too late: those instructions are traveling at the same speed as the data itself, it will always remain ahead of them.

Answer (score 1):

### The Documents are in Plain Sight

You’ve already deployed the cache. It’s on Pirate Bay and other torrent sites, already residing on hundreds or thousands of hard drives.

Copies are on web sites you or your friends own, just slightly off the beaten path at “main.html” instead of “index.html” and hidden from bots and scanners.

What you are relying on is that when you disappear, it’s going to get some people interested in you. When people start putting effort into reviewing your files and writings, they will find one (or several) of your caches.

Comment: I think many people will already be mighty interested before his disappearance. So it would come out a bit too early.

Comment: I would add to this method that the information is presented in a seeming innocuous format, something that keeps the key pieces away from each other so the puzzle's final image isn't clear - such that when scrutiny is raised, people's natural tendency to want answers triggers a small group of people to be invested enough to put it all together.  The risk of pre-release is still there, but where the gov't had one problem, now they have many.